# rsyslog - Different logs for different IP addresses?

Tags: rsyslog

Our network has devices scattered all over.  I'd like to do something like:

pool1 { 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.20, 192.168.1.50 }
pool2 { 192.168.1.21-192.168.1.40, 192.168.1.66 }

if from pool1 do this

if from pool2 do that

That way I could make logs from Macs look like Mac logs, Linux logs look like Linux logs, Cisco logs look like Cisco logs, etc.  I just haven't been able to find anything specific enough by Googling.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a decently recent version of [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) (*packages of the latest version can be found on their website*) then you should be able to use an array for comparison, as explained [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/control_structures.html). Something like:

```
if $fromhost-ip == [ "192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2"... ] then {
  action(...do this...)
}
```

Although from the [control structures documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/control_structures.html) it seems that it should be more like:

```
if $variable in [array]
```

If you have big range, you should be able to populate a local variable with a foreach structure like that. You can find more info about scripting if you search the docs for "RainerScript"

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
# accept logging for remote hosts on a per-ip-address basis
$template DirectoryPerHost,"/var/log/REMOTEHOSTS/%fromhost-ip%/%syslogfacility-text%.log"
if ( ( $fromhost-ip != "127.0.0.1" ) and (  $fromhost-ip != "::1" ) ) then  {
    ?DirectoryPerHost
} else {
    whatever you want to do with local log files here
}
```

There are other variables you can use instead of fromhost-ip - see the docs that Radu links to for more.

Radu is correct that you need a recent rsyslog to accomplish this.

If you are stuck on RHEL6 or one of its rebuilds, there is an rsyslog7 package from the OS you can use in place of the the default (old) rsyslog.  The default version doesn't support this syntax but v7 does.